# Define & Use Custom renderer Django Rest Framework View

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, renderer

I'm trying to override a CSV renderer import for a django rest framework view. Here's how so:

```
class CustomCSVRenderer(BaseCSVRenderer):
   def render():
      do something

   def tablize():
      do something
```

I've defined the `CustomCSVRenderer` in the same python class `views.py` as the view in question:

```
class MyView(ListAPIView, CustomMixinSet):

    renderer_classes = (CustomRenderer, JSONRenderer)
```

When I try to debug this implementation, my pdb debugger never hits the CustomCSVRenderer and instead I get a response based on some underlying renderer used by django restframework.

What could be the issue? How do I know what renderer django rest framework is using?

Comment: You haven't set the media_type and format attributes of the trenderer as shown in [the docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#custom-renderers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *@Daniel Roseman* stated in the comment section, you'll need to do a little bit more in order to make this custom renderer work.

From the docs:

> To implement a custom renderer, **you should override `BaseRenderer`, set the `.media_type` and `.format` properties**, and implement the `.render(self, data, media_type=None, renderer_context=None)` method.

Thus, your `CustomCSVRenderer` should look like this:

```
class CustomCSVRenderer(BaseCSVRenderer):
    media_type = 'text/csv'
    format = 'csv'

    def render(self, data, media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
       ...
```